# Is there any way to compress ..eex HTML templates for production?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using `Phoenix` to render html. It's going well, but returned HTML is not compressed in `prod` environment. I know there is gzip, but it's another thing: I'm talking about removing comments, newlines and so on, not archiving.

Is there any way to compress returned html on from templates (possibly on compilation step)?

Comment: What tools would you use to minimize HTML outside of Elixir?  I don't think you need anything Elixir-specific.

Comment: Google "minimize html files" and you'll find a few options for that.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci man, how would I edit compressed files this case? It looks like ydk elixir

Comment: You did say "possibly on compilation step".  If you minimize the html after compilation (which seemed that it might be acceptable because of your use of the word "possibly") then I fail to see how this would be anything Elixir-specific.  After compilation I'd simply shell out to a CLI tool to minimize things.  If you're trying to minimize within the browser pipeline, that is a different issue.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the best alternative would be to define a custom eex engine that would strip the whitespace. It is a bit of work to do, but not that many.

EEx is build in a way that the thing that actually compiles the template (the engine) is pluggable - Phoenix already takes advantage of this by defining an engine that properly HTML-escapes the dynamic values. You could build on top the the [phoenix engine](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/7a78a43b20059e8f5355c372df73962556ec7b53/lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex) to strip the unwanted data form static chunks - you'd do this in the `handle_text/2` callback of the engine. The other callbacks could be easily delegated to the phoenix implementation.

This, of course, would only take care of the static whitespace and comments that are known at compile-time. But I think it's a good enough solution for many cases.

Answer (score 2):

To minify the files on the fly, one could use a custom `Plug` in `:browser` pipeline:

**router.ex**

```
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    ...
    plug :minify_html
    ...
  end
```

I was unable to quickly google for the existing one, maybe you would need to implement it yourself.

---

Other possibility would be to use any `brunch` minifier (e. g. [`html-pages-brunch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pages-brunch) or like) to produce intermediate `.eex` files in production. That way you put your templates somewhere out of generic phoenix tree (e. g. in `/web/templates.origin`) and instruct the minifier to build minified templates inside the normal `/web/templates` folder. In `dev` that brunch rule should probably just copy the origin to templates.